# Should I 'admit' a weakness of a paper even if it's 'obvious'?

Tags: writing, writing-style

Example: I have a simulation to run that requires social media data sets. The data sets that actually matter are too big to be able to simulate anything useful on. Instead, I picked a data set that's much smaller that had similar properties and I (hoped) would therefore have similar behavior.

One thing I discovered was that different data sets, even when they're of a similar size, can behave radically different in ways that I'm not exactly able to predict from those properties.

Obviously this is a major weakness of the paper, because now I don't have a way to even guarantee that those 'similar properties' even matter anymore.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what sort of "obvious" weakness this is; it seems too undefined to be "obvious". An example of something that I would think of as an "obvious" weakness is one that is already clear from the sample; for example, if your sample is clearly described as coming from medical practice in the United States, it probably isn't necessary to state that your results may not hold in medical practice in the UK: you've already covered that by describing your sample. Your issue, however, sounds much more insidious and methodological.

Comment: Have you explored the reasons for variation in the data sets?  Maybe you are looking at rare events? Or maybe (social media) there's a troll in there in some sets?  For example, if there is somebody playing silly games on one social media platform, the interactions may poison the data on that platform.

Answer (score 16):

I wonder if your research is ready for prime time. Not getting consistent results and not knowing why is a fault. Maybe you should continue work for a bit.

But for the question itself, it is better that any shortcomings come from you rather than from someone else.

At a minimum, you have an interesting "future research" section to write. Maybe you should find a way to look at the larger data sets or others that will give you better insight into what is really going on.

Answer (score 2):

> Example: I have a simulation to run that requires social media data-sets. The data-sets that actually matter are too big to be able to simulate anything useful on. Instead, I picked a data-set that's much smaller that had similar properties and I (hoped) would therefor have similar behavior.
>
> One thing I discovered was that different data-sets, even when they're of a similar size, can behave radically different in ways that I'm not exactly able to predict from those properties.

I would say you have an interesting discovery there: datasets X and Y which seemed similar actually aren't all that similar. There's some kind of difference between them that your simulation technique can bring to light.

Since you say the datasets you originally wanted to study are intractably large and your smaller datasets can't be trusted to generalize, your research has hit an obstacle. But you also have interesting new research avenues:

- Can you find out what difference in the datasets causes them to behave differently in the simulation?
- Now that you know what difference you're looking for, can you come up with a more focused, efficient test to figure out which class a given dataset belongs to?
- Can you use your efficient test to figure out which of your smaller datasets is most similar to your big datasets?

It's always a good thing to be open to surprise discoveries instead of rigidly only sticking to your original research question.

> Obviously this is a major weakness of the paper, because now I don't have a way to even guarantee that those 'similar properties' even matter anymore.

Well, you now know that it's not safe to assume you can generalize your results on the small datasets to the larger ones. If you don't point this out you would be misleading your readers, and producing **bad science**.

Another option is to discuss with your supervisor if it's possible to access heavy-duty computing resources that will enable you to process the original large datasets, given that you've shown that you can't properly substitute in the smaller datasets.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I 'admit' a weakness of a paper even if it's 'obvious'?

Yes, as per [Buffy's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/142480/22768).

Delving deeper: You *discovered...different data-sets...can behave radically different[ly and unpredictably]*. You acknowledge *this is a major weakness of the paper*. So, a better title might be "*Should I 'admit' a major weakness of a paper even if it's 'obvious'?*" Given that you did not expect the weakness, perhaps even

> *Should I 'admit' a major weakness of a paper?*

Again, yes.

You should consider whether a paper with major weaknesses is publishable. If you can establish why results are *radically different* between datasets / you can *predict* when differences will arise, then you can perhaps change a major weakness into a strength, simply by explaining that your simulation works for data sets that produce predictable results and defer consideration of other data sets to future work. That said,

> data-sets that actually matter are too big to be able to simulate anything useful on

You also need to explain why your simulations are interesting, given that meaningful data sets cannot be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Not a weakness but a ‘limitation’. All research has limitations due to reductionism. It’s a feature not a failure.